# PHP MySQL Query with scandir listing both

Tags: php, html, directory

I've a directory of images and a database, with the same image filenames.
I'm trying to create a table that will display the list of images in the first column and the filename, listed in the database that equals the image name in the next column.
Any image that aren't listed in the database would then be listed at the end/or start of the table, showing those that aren't being used by the site.

```
//select the data from the database ready for calling
$sql = "SELECT * from userImages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;}
//Table index row
echo "<table><tr><td>File</td><td>DbListing</td></tr>";
//collects the filenames from the directory
define('IMAGEPATH', 'preload-images-thumbs/');
if (is_dir(IMAGEPATH)){
    $handle = opendir(IMAGEPATH);}
else{echo 'No image directory';}
$directoryfiles = array();
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    $newfile = str_replace(' ', '_', $file);
    rename(IMAGEPATH . $file, IMAGEPATH . $newfile);
    $directoryfiles[] = $newfile;}
foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH.'*') as $filename){
$dir_image=basename($filename);
//lists the filenames from the directory in the first column
echo "<tr><td>".basename($filename)."</td><td>";
//lists the rows of image names from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  //this just dumps the whole list on the first row of the next column in the table
echo $row["Image_dir"];}
echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

What happens in the snippet above just dumps the list from the database in the first row. Do I need to explode this and how do I match each line with a filename that exists and run off the surplus image at the end?

So after some additions and flipping the code around somewhat, I came up with this:

```
//select the data from the database ready for calling
$sql = "SELECT * from userImages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;}
//Table index row
echo "<table><tr><td>File</td><td>DbListing</td></tr>";
//collects the filenames from the directory
define('IMAGEPATH', 'preload-images-thumbs/');
if (is_dir(IMAGEPATH)){
    $handle = opendir(IMAGEPATH);}
else{echo 'No image directory';}
$directoryfiles = array();
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    $newfile = str_replace(' ', '_', $file);
    rename(IMAGEPATH . $file, IMAGEPATH . $newfile);
    $directoryfiles[] = $newfile;}
foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH.'*') as $filename){
$dir_image=basename($filename);
//lists the filenames from the directory in the first column
echo "<tr><td>".basename($filename)."</td><td>";
//lists the rows of image names from the database
$sql = "SELECT * from userImages WHERE Image_dir='$filename'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so exiting";
    exit;}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result or die(mysql_error()))); {
  //this just dumps the whole list on the first row of the next column in the table
 (explode(" ",$row["Image_dir"]));}
echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

This now returns the first image in the directory, in the first column, but tells me:

"No rows found, nothing to print so exiting"

...when it is clearly listed in the database....

|**Images directory**         | **Database listing**           |

| Apples.jpg                  | No rows found, nothing to print so exiting  |

So, it looks like its getting somewhere, but not quite getting there yet :-/

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated and not supported. Use `mysqli` or PDO instead

Comment: Your 2nd while loop does not start any html table rows, just ends them.

Comment: thats the point I'm making... how do i spread it over the rows.

Comment: mysql works (to an effect) mysqli gives errors (with no effect)